# Invalid identity provider: sitecoreidentityserver when attempting to login

Tags: azure, paas, identity-server

Attempted to simply login to two different sitecore CM ( test and prod ) Azure PaaS servers and go the following error :

Invalid identity provider: sitecoreidentityserver

I suspect it has to do with Azure changing something or a config file not agreeing.  We are only seeing this at Azure and not in local.  We made no major deployments and this happened over the weekend.

Comment: Did you check the Sitecore Identity file \App_config\Sitecore\Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer\Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.config? Another thing is check if the are any rewrite rules that might be tranforming URLs to lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was because of URL Rewrite.

If you add certain redirects to your rewrite list, you can affect other redirects such as the redirect to SI.  Make sure your redirects are not affecting functionality after you deploy them.

Answer (score 0):

This happened for us while trying to introduce a URL redirect for non-lowercase URLs to lowercase URLs via IIS rewrite rule.

```
<rule name="Convert to lower case" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*[A-Z].*" ignoreCase="false" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{R:0}}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```